# @property Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I've been following some tutorials, and I have a question regarding `@property` with an instance variable in my class, which is another class.

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject{
    int width;
    int height;
    XYpoint *origin;
}

@property int width, height;
```

I have my `XYpoint` class in another file, and everything works fine. But in the tutorial I've been following, in the main program, they create a "Rectangle *r", and use dot syntax with an origin variable just like this:

```
r.origin = ****;
```

I've been searching for a way to add object variables to `@property` but I haven't found anything. I've been trying to add it in several ways but without success. I hope someone can help me with this.

I've tried things like adding another:

```
 "@property XYpoint *origin" and "@synthesize *origin"
```

also without the asterisk, and several other ways.

Comment: The `@property XYPoint *origin` is correct, but you don't need the asterisk for `@synthesize origin`.

Comment: In the @synthesize origin; it gives me the error "Existing ivar 'origin' for unsafe_unretained property 'origin' must be __unsafe_unretained"

Comment: You need to declare it like this `@property (strong)`, recommended this `@property (nonatomic, strong)`.  Read the document I gave in my answer thoroughly!!

Comment: thnks man now it works, i´m giving it a look now, thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 2):

You already have an instance variable `XYpoint *origin`, so what you want is to create a property that is backed by that instance variable and synthesize it. I usually use an underscore prefix on the ivar so that you don't end up with confusing shadowing warnings or accidentally refer to the wrong one, but that's up to you. Something like this:

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject {
    XYpoint *_origin;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) XYpoint *origin;

@end

@implementation

@synthesize origin = _origin;

// rest of your class

@end
```

Now when using that class, you should be able to refer to the property using dot syntax:

```
Rectangle *rect = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
XYpoint *pointFromRect = rect.origin;
```

Answer (score 1):

Properties are such a fundamental basic part of objective-c that you should master them before doing anything else.  Whether or not you need the `*` on your property depends on what kind of variable it is.  If it is a stack variable (struct, int, float, etc) then it doesn't need it generally.  If it is a heap object (any class) then it needs it.  However, you never need the `*` on the synthesize.  Also, you don't need to declare an explicit iVar for it, the compiler will make one automatically.  This has been the case for a while now.

Read this -> [The Objective-C Programming Language : Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html)

Comment: Regarding the automatic ivars, I like to be able to see my ivars in the debugger, so often still declare them manually... I haven't checked recently but they were never visible to the debugger previously when automatically created.

Comment: @Stew If they aren't visible, I just print them out real quick with a debugger command (po foo, etc.).  However, they usually are (I just checked real quick, and I could see my properties under `self`)

Answer (score 0):

Using @property and @synthesize, you create getters and setters automatically so that you can access the object/variable to some other class. As wquist mentioned, your @synthesize do not need asterix. see, you have created property for width and height. They have same purpose, accessing in other class.